# Connect to WiFi without storing password (Raspbian)

Tags: linux, security, wpa

I notice WPA_GUI has saved my WiFi password to  `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.  The unit I'm trying to set up is a shared use system on enterprise WiFi that logs on with a user's account, so leaking the password between users is a very bad thing.  There's no option in WPA_GUI to not save the password.

How can I set the system up to force each user to give their username/password to connect, and not have them stored?  Note I would prefer **to avoid using actual corresponding user accounts on the system.**

Comment: @goldilocks I'm not nearly so worried about reading out memory, but one user being able to read all previous users' passwords is much more serious.  With respect to your edits, just to be clear, are you saying I could have a seperate account with access to GPIO and wifi but no sudo?  Then whoever had root (i.e. me) could still read the passwords if WPA_GUI wrote them to the file, and if it didn't, then presumably wpa_supplicant couldn't connect

Comment: Even if there's only one physical user at a time, it would not be impossible for someone to leave something on the system to grab passwords later.  Of course, most people are probably savvy enough to recognize that this kind of setup is not all that secure -- just beware if it is very important, you need to do some hard thinking about it.

Comment: @goldilocks there are many ways to grab passwords with root access, some of which aren't fundamentally different from ones I played with in the DOS days.  There's a big gap between those and reading a file which is stored anyway, not least in responsibility.  I don't have to prevent people installing/writing malware, As the default behaviour approximates keylogging I do have to avoid that./

Comment: **I'm not talking about root access.** I'm presuming this user *doesn't* have root access, and my point about using the same account for everyone is it makes it drop dead easy for anyone to do anything they want to anyone else using the same account.  They would barely even have to be able to shell script.  You could keylog with 2 lines of `.sh` under X.  If it's not that important, who cares, but you were warned.

Comment: @goldilocks well at the moment they have sudo, though you've pointed out a way round that.

Comment: I forgot about the crazy privileges on Raspbian...you can crank those down BTW.  It is unusually permissive.  You'll find a lot of stuff here about `sudo` and `/etc/sudoers` if you need it.  Simple keylogging under X isn't rootkit level keylogging -- it only applies to the current session of the current user.

Comment: ...the nasty is `xinput test-xi2`, which exploits a not hard to figure out underlying mechanism you can't get rid of.   There's various discussions [linked through this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178942/25985).

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for your suggestions, I've been away since then.  Current session/current user stuff really isn't an issue here (the pi will be switched off between users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using a wired network -- at the same time as I was failing to get NetworkManager/nm-applet working we got permission to plug the Pis in to the network.  However I know from Xubuntu that nm-applet can connect to WPA2/PEAP and prompt for a password every time, so this *should* be the solution.